# how to sum multiple columns using one criteria query?

Tags: mysql, grails, criteria

For Example , lets say a table "values" contains 4 columns A,B,C and D. Now, I want to add B,C,D where A = 10.

For single column , it is like this :

```
def c=values.createCriteria{
eq("A",10)
projections{
sum("B")
}
}
```

How to add B,C and D where A=10 ?

Comment: If I tell you that the SQL query for that looks like this... SELECT B+C+D bcd FROM values WHERE A=10 ... does that help?

Comment: Could you tell me how to write a criteria query for the same. ?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
def c=values.createCriteria().get{
eq("A",10)
 projections{
  sum("B","b")
  sum("C","c")
  sum("D","d")
 }
 resultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
}
```

then you can construct a map or list [sumB:c.b,sumbC:c.c,sumD:c.d]
something like that OR

```
def bcd=c.b+c.c+c.d
```

to get your final value and sorry if this isn't even close of what you want but that's what i get from your explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following: 
    `SELECT B,C,D,(B+C+D) AS sum FROM values WHERE A=10;` OR 
`SELECT (B+C+D) AS sum FROM values WHERE A=10;`

Think it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I know how to write a SQL query for that.I want to know how to write a criteria query for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write like this in controller:

`def sumList = Values.executeQuery("SELECT (B+C+D) AS sum FROM Values WHERE A=10")
println(sumList)`

Ref link: http://grails.asia/grails-hql-count-examples